# AJAX call PHP checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Having a problem with simple AJAX call that checks if checkbox is checked.
At the moment, no matter if the checkbox is checked or not, it would print "not checked". I've tried changing "POST"/"GET" methods in he PHP code, but the result is same, i dont know why? any ideas?thanks!

```
      #test.html
      <html>
      <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function load()
        {
           var xmlhttp;
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
           {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
             xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
           }
           else
           {// code for IE6, IE5
               xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {
                 document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","checkbox.php",true);
          xmlhttp.send();
         }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

      <input type="checkbox" value="value1" name="check1"/>BOX 1</input>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="value2" name="check2">BOX 2</input>
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="load()">Run</button>
      <div id="div1"></div>

      </body>
      </html>


      #checkbox.php
      <?php
      if(isset($_GET['check1'])        
      {
         echo "checked";
      }
      else
      {
         echo "not checked";
      }   
      ?>
```

Comment: Please don't tell me you seriously have to support IE5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually send any values to `checkbox.php` when making the AJAX request, so `$_GET['check1']` will never have a value.  Thus the `else` block is always reached.

Inside your `load()` function you need to determine the current state of the checkboxes and send that state to the server in the AJAX request.  Something like this might be able to determine that state:

```
var checkedBox = '';
if (document.getElementsByName('check1')[0].checked) {
    checkedBox = 'check1';
} else if (document.getElementsByName('check2')[0].checked) {
    checkedBox = 'check2';
}
```

So `checkedBox` would hold the name of the first checkbox that's currently checked (kind of assuming radio button functionality here, but you can tweak as needed for whatever you're trying to accomplish), or an empty value if nothing is checked.

Then you can use that in a URL value:

```
var ajaxUrl = 'checkbox.php';
if (checkedBox !== '') {
    ajaxUrl += '?' + checkedBox + '=true';
}
```

So, for example, if `check1` is checked then the resulting `ajaxUrl` value would be:

```
checkbox.php?check1=true
```

If nothing is checked, it would just be:

```
checkbox.php
```

Then use that URL in your AJAX request:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', ajaxUrl, true);
```

This can all be refactored and simplified I'm sure, but I tried to break it out into logical steps that you can observe and learn from.  It's definitely also worth stating that you don't even *need* to use AJAX for this, since you can just determine the state of the checkboxes and display a message entirely client-side.  I'm *guessing* you're doing this as a learning exercise for AJAX, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Indeed, I'm new to AJAX and learning the very basics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of using AJAX for this, can't you just check in javascript if the checkbox is checked or not ?

Anyhow I'm more used to jQuery but it doesn't seem that you are sending any data, you need to test if the checkbox is checked in javascript and send the result in your request.